# I have one series as '12345234123123543'. How to write a function in SQL to find out which digit has most occurrence in a given series?

Tags: sql

I have one series as '12345234123123543'. How to write a function in SQL to find out which digit has most occurrence in a given series?

Comment: tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: I think a procedural program will fit your needs rather than SQL.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server then You may do like this

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX)='12345234123123543'

;WITH CTE AS(
     SELECT CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(1)) AS CH, 1 AS CNT
     UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@Str,CNT,1)AS NVARCHAR(1)) AS CH , CNT+1
     FROM CTE 
     WHERE CNT<=LEN(@Str)
)
SELECT TOP 1 CH,COUNT(CH) 
FROM CTE
WHERE CH <> '' 
GROUP BY CH 
ORDER BY COUNT(CH) DESC
```

Comment: What I would be interested about; is this faster in execution or @a_horse_with_no_name's answer?

Comment: Hi @ManuelMannhardt, I don`t know much more about postgres sql. so I cant say any thing on it. But as per my experience CTE always do better in performance perspective

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt: I'm pretty sure the combination of `string_to_array()` and `unnest()` in Postgres is faster then the corresponding CTE solution (which would be possible in Postgres as well)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Postgres you can use the following:

```
select c, count(*) as cnt
from unnest(string_to_array('12345234123123543',null)) as t(c)
group by c
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

Output:

```
c | cnt
--+----
3 |   5
```

---

Edit: inspired by Jaydip's answer, this can indeed be expressed with standard SQL only:

```
with recursive cte (ch, cnt) as (
     values ('', 1)
     union all
     select substring('12345234123123543' from cnt for 1) as ch, cnt+1
     from cte 
     where cnt <= character_length('12345234123123543')
)
select ch, count(ch) 
from cte
where ch <> '' 
group by ch 
order by count(ch) desc
fetch first 1 rows only
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew SQL could do such cool things. Maybe its time for me to dig deeper into it then just doing select/insert/update and delete :D

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt: that's not 100% "standard SQL". `string_to_array()` is a Postgres extension, but `unnest()` is actually part of the standard (`limit` would need to be replaced with `fetch first 1 rows only` in standard SQL)

Comment: Oh ok, sad that I am using MySQL most of the time. But still, I saw many cool things you can do with it in the last year or so, just never bothered with it. What excactly does unnest()? string_to_array is quite clear to me.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt: `unnest()` turns an array into a set of rows.